# No module named 'imgaug'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, python-import, importerror

I've used `pip install imgaug` to successfully install `imgaug` in my environment `tensorflow_gpu` already, and when I import `imgaug` in Anaconda Prompt and it looked fine.
[Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhVsG.png)

However, when I try to import `imgaug` in jupyter notebook, it said "No module named 'imgaug'". My OS platform is windows10. I don't know what's wrong here and can anybody help? Thanks.
[jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw6NA.png)

Comment: If you don't want to sort getting the environment linked to the environment where the kernel backing Jupyter is, you can try running `conda install -c conda-forge imgaug` (if that doesn't work, then fall back to trying `%pip install imgaug`) inside a cell in the notebook where you want to import imgaug. After you run that in a cell in the notebook, restart the kernel, and then try the import in a cell in the notebook. The magic versions of those commands insure the installations happen in the same environment underlying the kernel backing the notebook, ...

Comment: <continued> see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magics. The best thing for the long run you can do when using conda is to stick to using conda as much as you can. It will make your environments more robust and portable. However, not everything is available in conda solely and sometimes you're left with mixing-and-matching in the effort to get something to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved the same issue today on Windows 10. I just copied folders imgaug and imgaug-0.4.0.dist-info from Python311\Lib\site-packages folder to Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages folder. It worked! I don't understand why pip and conda so often do not synchronyze, but usually you just have to duplicate the same things both for Python/pip and Anaconda/conda